# SEO on jQuery.toggle Links. Whats the lowdown?

Tags: jquery, seo, hyperlink, hidden

Sorry for the, strange title, but I couldnt quite get it across.

Basically what I've got is.

The HTML

```
<li class="dedicated">Dedicated Servers</li>
<li class="sub-link dedi-2">Dual Core Servers</li>
<li class="sub-link dedi-4">Quad Core Servers</li>
<script>Dedicated()</script>
```

The Javascript

```
function Dedicated(){
$(".dedicated").click(function () {
$(".dedi-2").toggle('fast');
$(".dedi-4").toggle('fast');
});
}
```

The CSS

```
#navigation .sub-link{display:none; text-indent:23px;}
#navigation .dedi-2{background-image:url(images/cpu-sprite.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 18px 4px;}
#navigation .dedi-4{background-image:url(images/cpu-sprite.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 18px -23px;}
```

Basically, thats the structure Im using at the moment. However, my links start of using display:none; and I've been lead to believe that this will mean google or crawlers will just ignore these links.

Could somebody clarify this for me or provide me with a possible solution?

Thanks

Owen

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547426/google-seo-and-hidden-elements

Comment: this link provided an answer I supose, althought still not 100% sure. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sees content under display:none, link too. Google may penalized if someone hide content for spam o key stuffing, but it's not your case. If you want Matt Cutts published a video about it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpK1VGJN4XY